# How to create an interactive image with HTML5, Javascript, DOM and CSS

Tags: javascript, mysql, css, html, dom

So here's the problem:
I want to create a webpage based interactive map/image. A user can click anywhere in the image to create a red house or a green house at that point. Then they can fill in a form with attributes to that newly created house object like Name, size etc
[image: Interactive map]

When the user has chosen his/her type of house from a radio button selection, they click inside the map and the a small house image loads on the point they clicked on. (A new house object has been created).

The newly created objects' properites (like name, position) should be maintained (saved in a mysql database, server side) so that the next time the map loads up (either on refresh, browser restart, deletion of cookies), the house objects load in the right place on the map.

I also would like the user to be able to make changes or delete the house objects.
Responsiveness of the interactive map/image would be an added benefit.

My problem is I don't know how to go about this (fit the pieces together, you can say). I have basic knowledge of HTML, CSS, PHP, Javascript, DOM, jquery, mySQL. So how can I create such an interactive image or map? Any guidance or solution that can point me in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Backend**

At first you need to define a database with a table for your houses with the properties you want to store. To store the houses position you need a x- and y-coorinate for every house. I would recommend doing it in percent or in another relative coordinate format, so that if you change the image size in the browser the houses are still correctly positioned without having to recalculate the position from absolute pixel values.

Then you need a script to access the database and to fetch, create, edit and delete houses, you mentioned you have knowledge of PHP, so you could write a very simple one-file API: houses.php
In this file you establish a database connection to your previously created database and define all the functions you need (e.g. fetch, create, edit and delete). Which function you want to execute in each call to the API could be told over a URL-Parameter. E.g. *houses.php?action=fetch* could return you a JSON-list with all the houses stored in the database. So in the houses.php you would call a function based on the action-parameter in the URL. In a function you would echo the output as JSON string (PHP already has functions for that).

**Frontend**

Ok, now your backend is set up. But you still need the frontend: 
You have a simple HTML-file where you include all your javascript and CSS files. For a good CSS-layout I recommend [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
Then you have the image on the left and the controls on the right. Now you need to load the houses that are already in your database. So after the document is ready, there is a jQuery-Event for that, you make an AJAX-call (jQuery is also good for that) to your API with *houses.php?action=fetch* which will return you the houses as an JSON-Object which can easily be used in javascript. Store that object in a variable so that you can access the information for all the houses.

Then you need a function to draw all the houses you have stored on the map, based on their properties (position and color).

And you need a click event on the map, when the user starts to create a house that you can create a new house on the map and initialize the controls on the right. In the CSS you need to set the house-image position to relative and the houses position to absolute, so that the houses can be displayed as overlay above the image. And remember storing the houses position in a relative format like percent to the underlaying image.

Then you need events for all the created houses. So that if the user selects a house it can be identified via a HTML data-attribute e.g. data-id="house ID". This id can then be used to get the house from your stored list of all houses to display the name etc. in the controls on the right.

Another important event would be the click on the button to save or delete the currently selected house. In this event you can call a function to check for validation of the input and make the AJAX call to your API. To store or to delete objects you should set the method to 'PUT' or 'DELETE' in the AJAX call.

To start developing all this I can recommend XAMPP as a local development environment. I hope this answer fits the pieces a little together and gives an overview of the things you need to build.

Comment: Amazing! I will try this tonight. I will be back with updates.

Comment: You can also try http://leafletjs.com/ and custom markers. And you can save user objects properties in browser localstorage and worry about backend later.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while but I figured I should provide an update on how I accomplished this.

If you want to make an interactive map of any sort, use Leaflet (http://leafletjs.com/). It's nothing short of amazing and has lots of functionality and plugins.

To create the kind of map I described:

1. Use leaflet

   2. In leaflet js, set/create a non-geographical map
   3. To create the house icons, use leaflets custom markers api to either use a static image as an icon or use CSS to render one.
   4. Since Leaflet is JS, you can set up Event listeners in the code that can react to the user clicking on different items on the map.
   5. You can use JQuery and Ajax to store information about the nodes/markers in a server-side database and in turn get info about
      the nodes/markers from a server-side db.
   6. Marker postions can be saved as latitudes and longtitudes in an array that is sent to the server (and retrieved too).
   7. Use refresh and timeouts to keep updating info about the map nodes or data